# Split credit card number into 4 chunks using Regex lookahead?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to chunk a credit card number (*in my case I always have 16 digits*) into 4 chunks of 4 digits.

I've succeeded doing it via positive look ahead :

```
var s="4581458245834584";
var t=Regex.Split(s,"(?=(?:....)*$)");
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

But I don't understand why the result is with two padded empty cells:

[image]

I already know that I can use "Remove Empty Entries" flag , But I'm not after that.
However - If I change the regex to `(?=(?:....)+$)` , then I get this result :

[image]

**Question**

Why does the regex emit empty cells ? and how can I fix my regex so it produce 4 chunks at first place ( without having to 'trim' those empty entries )

Comment: Isnt a card number always 16 digits? Assuming as much, isnt a regex over the top? Couldn't you just aplit based on that with rx or manually?

Comment: @ChrisWatts There are probably 10 ways of doing it. I want to do it with regex. I already have the split solution  ( one line) so I'm 95% on the way. I just need this 5% to fix the code.( and understand why those extra empty cells are emitted).

Comment: fair enough, just was my inmediate thought!

Comment: Be aware that different brands of payment card use different lengths of card number. Not all are sixteen digits. Also, the first six digits of a payment card number form the IIN (or "BIN" number) which identify the issuing bank, so it's probably useful to split that part out separately. And regex is very expensive for such a simple task; use a simple substring instead to split out each portion of interest.

Comment: @Bobulous It happen once when the page loads. It is not running thousands of thousands of time .This nano optimization shouldn't be a consideration ( in this specific task).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I don't understand why the result is with two padded empty cells:
>   Let's try breaking down your regex.

**Regex:** `(?=(?:....)*$)`

**Explanation:** Lookahead (?=) for *anything* 4 times(?:....) for zero or more times. Just looking ahead and matching nothing will match **zero width**.

Since you are using `*` quantifier which says *zero or more* it matches first zero width at beginning or string and also at end of string.

Visualize it from this snapshot of [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/81jG2O/1)

[[image: Zero Width visualization.[2]]

> So How can I select only those 3 splitters in the middle ?

I don't know C# very well but this 3 step method might work for you.

1. Search with `(\d{4})` and replace with `-\1`. Result will be `-4581-4582-4583-4584`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/81jG2O/2)
2. Now replace first `-` by searching with `^-`. Result will be `4581-4582-4583-4584`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/81jG2O/3/)
3. At last search for `-` and split on it. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/81jG2O/4/). Used `\n` to substitute for demo purpose.

**Alternative Solution Inspired from Royi's answer.**

**Regex:** `(?=(?!^)(?:\d{4})+$)`

**Explanation:**

```
(?=              // Look ahead for
   (?!^)         // Not the start of string
   (?:\d{4})+$   // Multiple group of 4 digits till end of string
)
```

[image: Regex Tracking]

Since nothing is matched and only lookaround assertions are used, it will pinpoint Zero width after a group of 4 digits.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/81jG2O/6)**</kbd>

Comment: So How can I select only those 3 splitters in the middle ?

Comment: @Royi, do not only use a lookahead modifier, but for example also additionally use a look-behind modifier to express that any split-point has to be preceded by 4 digits... ;)

Comment: @elgonzo (side note) This will make this - unavailable to JS.

Comment: @Royi, if JS compatibility is a concern, would it be okay for you to just match each 4 digits instead of matching the split points, or was precisely this the challenge?

Comment: @elgonzo I don't want to mislead anyone - that's why I wrote  "side note". But I prefer that it will also be valid with JS regex . but - since this question is not tagged with JS , I should except also c# only solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Umm, I don't know WHY you need Regex for this. You just overcomplicate things. Better way is to just split it manually:

```
var values = new List<int>();
for(int i =0;i < 4;i++)
{
    var value = int.Parse(s.Substring(i*4, 4));
    values.Add(value);
}
```

Regex solution:

```
        var s = "4581458245834584";
        var separated = Regex.Match(s, "(.{4}){4}").Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: 1 line doesn't make it better in any way. You just throw complexety into Regex query. You using pattern mather for simple separation problem where you by all means can deal with less blood and more efficient solution from beginning. The question itself never would have came up if you just chosen most simplistic path.

Comment: Mmm , I think the context was set with the regex tag at first place .

Comment: Well, unless you deal with entire payment card grammar - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number I see this solution as complex and not debuggable at all.

Comment: I would've removed this irrelevant comment "_If you so obsessed with regex_". It's not professional , and irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Just fyi: you could simplify your regex a little: `Regex.Matches(s, ".{4}").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray()`...
Now, isn't `.{4}` a wonderful regex... :-P

Comment: Well, it will be awful in any way =P

Comment: I got to be honest and tell you that indeed my regex has the worst performance as opposed to the other solutions of yours.  ( it only executed once in my page - but still). here are the testings https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaW1p.png ( not surprising though , but still I was expected that the third will be slower than the second). Thanks.

Comment: If you not sure about performance of your regex - put it into something like RegexBuddy. It will show you all backtracking that happens when engine fails to accomplish internal matching. Well, it is always the reason why Regex is slow. It provides wide functionality but can surprise you sometimes. Try to run 'x+x+x+' on some 'xxxxxxxxy' string. Lookup works similar way, with small difference - it's not capturing anything.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like I've found an answer.

Looking at those splitters - I needed to get rid of the edges :

[image]

So I thought -  how can I tell the regex engine "not at the start of the line " ?

Which is  exactly what `(?!^)` does

So here is the new regex :

```
var s="4581458245834584";
var t=Regex.Split(s,"(?!^)(?=(?:....)+$)");
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Clever one. It didn't crossed my mind to avoid checking at beginning. Still an explanation to this would be good.

Comment: Even [(?=(?!^)(?:....)+$)](https://regex101.com/r/81jG2O/5) works. Confused how to explain this.

Comment: @Rahul: Your regex says: Look for something that is followed by 4 characters which are not at the start of the input string. More precisely, your look-ahead pattern says: Continue with matching at this position only if this position is not the start of the input string...

Comment: @Rahul, oops sorry, didn't notice :)

Comment: This is an excellent example of the old saying that calling a piece of code “clever” is a huge red flag. If you know – as stated in the question – that you have exactly 16 digits and you want four 4-digit junks, just use a string splitting function. Regex, and especially such a monster of a regex, is a horribly wrong tool for the job. I wouldn’t let this pass code review in a million years.

Comment: @besc If you find this regex _"such a monster of a regex"_ then you're in the wrong business. Check out the Email RFC regex. ( really , just open browser and google it).

Comment: It’s not a monster on its own; it becomes a monster for this particular task. I mean, come on! Getting into looakhead/lookbehind land for cutting a string into quarters. Seriously? Email addresses according to the letter of the RFC are a good example as well, thanks for mentioning. That’s the other end of the spectrum where regex is the wrong tool. Assuming that completely throwing readability and maintainability out of the window is not an option the full RFC specification of a valid email address is complex enough to warrant a dedicated parser.

Comment: @besc Like I've said in comments , beside the 10 other ways I could do it , I wanted this time to do it in REGEX , to enhance my regex skills. I don't see anything wrong with trying different approaches.

Answer (score 2):

It has been mentioned already that the `*` quantifier also matches at the end of string where there are zero group-matches ahead. To avoid matching at start and end you can use `\B` *non [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)* which only matches between two *word characters* not giving matches for start and end.

```
\B(?=(?:.{4})+$)
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eS3gfn/1)

Because the lookahead won't be triggered at start or end of the string you could even [use `*`](https://regex101.com/r/eS3gfn/2)